# How do I bring my header forward via CSS?

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm having a problem with my site

I need the header to come forward, its running on wordpress here is the link to the site: http://goo.gl/E1ErzD

and here is the code that makes the header float:

```
  #header {
  padding: 1.618em 0 0;
  margin-bottom: 3.631em;
  border-bottom: 4px double #e8e4e3;
  clear: both;
  position: fixed;
```

Comment: You can "bring it forward" by changing the `z-index` property...but you'll still have problems.

Comment: @rnevius so I use     z-index: ?;

Comment: `#header { z-index: 100; }` ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set a `z-index`, and apply a `background-color` to the header in order for it to move forward. You should also consider setting a width:

```
#header {
 padding: 1.618em 0 0;
 margin-bottom: 3.631em;
 border-bottom: 4px double #e8e4e3;
 clear: both;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 9999;/* set this to something high*/
 background-color:#fff; /* so you can see it is a block */
 min-width:100%; /* play with this too, and asdjust margins. check in IE - you may have to set a width rather then min-width*/
```

Comment: Although this answer works, it's usually better to change the `z-index` to something logical, rather than `9999`.

Comment: @Demwunz this is great, however the front part is not filling up. and how do I make it transparent till 700px's down on scroll?

Comment: @RunnerRunner you will need to use JS in order to calculate the point at which you want to fill it. CSS isn't clever enough for your requirement. I'm sure a search around StackOverflow will pull something up for you!

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your css code for the header:

```
z-index: 1;
```